# How to automatically identify OneDrive Documents folder and redirect to it in Go?

Tags: windows, go, filesystems, onedrive

Well that's a tough one as it took me several hours first to understand what was going wrong.

I am writing a basic Go program that checks for the existence of a subfolder in my Documents folder (Windows). However, the program would keep telling me that this folder doesn't exist, although the same path copied in Windows Explorer would show me otherwise.

It turns out that all this time OneDrive had basically backed up my local Documents folder and also created some sort of magic alias mechanism that only works within Windows Explorer. In this case the subfolder was in fact not existing on my local Documents, so Go is right. But Windows Explorer would automatically redirect to the one existing on my One Drive. Concretely, if I copy such a path "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Subfolder" in Windows Explorer it will automatically redirect it to "C:\Users\Me\One Drive Me\Subfolder".

Is there any way I can actually figure this out automatically within Go? I am not even able to figure this out by using Windows PowerShell by using `Resolve-Path`, or by using `filepath.EvalSymlinks(dirPath)`. There seems to be a very special trick only happening in Windows Explorer.

Any hint, thank you!